# $_GET not picking up the variable

Tags: php

What am i doing wrong. The variable will not get picked up. I have tried to echo it out just to check but the echo was blank. What did i do wrong?

```
if($result->num_rows){
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
            //Displays them
            echo '<h4> <a href="request.php?='.$row['account_id'].'">' . $row['fname'] . '&nbsp' . $row['lname'] . '</a> <h4/>' .'<br/>';
            }
```

request.php below

```
$requestedId = $_GET['account_id'];
$userId = $_SESSION['user_id'];
```

Thats the portions of the code i need help with. The account id is passed through the URL.

Comment: You never gave the variable a name in your query string so you can't reference with one in your code. `<a href="request.php?='.$row['account_id'].'">' ` should be `<a href="request.php?account_id='.$row['account_id'].'">' `.

Answer (score 0):

In the while loop you need to put the name account_id in it, not just the value

```
echo '<h4> <a href="request.php?account_id='.$row['account_id'].'">' .
     $row['fname'] . '&nbsp' . $row['lname'] . '</a> <h4/>' .'<br/>';
```